# Does Knockout.mapping make ALL nested objects observable?

Tags: object, knockout.js, mapping, nested, observable

I am trying to map all possible nested objects of a JSON object so that each and every one is becomes an observable. I was under the impression that the use of `ko.mapping.fromJS` would result in all objects and their objects becoming observable. However, I am not seeing that happen.

If you look at the JSFiddle and code below you will see that the span initially displays the value "Test". My intention is for the button click to update the viewModel with the contents of `stuff2`, which should change the span's value to "Test2". However, the button click does not update anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eves/L5sgW/38/

HTML:

```
<p> <span>Name:</span>
<span data-bind="text: IntroData.Name"></span>
<button id="update" data-bind="click: Update">Update!</button>
</p>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var me = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, me);

    me.Update = function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff2, {}, windows.viewModel);
    };

    return me;
};

var stuff = {
    IntroData: {
        Name: 'Test'
    }
};

var stuff2 = {
    IntroData: {
        Name: 'Test2'
    }
};

window.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new ViewModel(stuff));
ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

Is it just that I have to make use of mapping options to have the nested objects be made observable? If so, what if the JSON object is so vast and complex (this one obviously isn't)? Can some recursive functionality be used to loop through each object's nested objects to make them all observable?

Comment: Note that you spelled `windows.viewModel` instead of `window.viewModel`. However, changing that gives me a "Max callstack size exceeded" message, still pondering exactly why. In any case, changing the argument to `me` [does the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/L5sgW/39/).

Comment: Changing to me certainly works for that jsfiddle.....sadly that doesn't fix the issue on the actual page. I will have to come back to this once I figure out what is different between the fiddle and the actual page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jeroen. You definitely fixed some of the issues that lead me to the real issue.... When I do my development I tend to do my work with Chrome developer tools and debugger in the javascript. Seems knockout and the debugger + Chrome Developer Tools don't play well together. When I take out the debugger or close the developer tools it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the Update function as below will work.

```
me.Update = function () {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff2, {}, windows.viewModel);
};
```